# inserting multiple records with classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

On a website that I am working on, users can add multiple form fields with a jQuery plugin.

But how can I insert these multiple records into the database?

```
    SQL = "INSERT INTO sehirler (memberid, sehiradi, sehirkodu, dateENTERED) VALUES ('"& Session("MEMBERID") &"', '"& sehiradi &"', '"& sehirkodu &"',  '"& NOW() &"')"
    Set objSehirEkle = objConn.execute(SQL)
```

Comment: You'll need to post more code before we have enough information to give a useful answer, but in the mean time PLEASE read [bobby-tables](http://bobby-tables.com).  You have a rather nasty Sql Injection vulnerability that needs to be fixed.

Comment: this is all there is, what else can I share with you?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply execute more than one SQL statement in one go, chaining them with semicolons:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1, Field2) VALUES ('name1', 1);" & _
      "INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1, Field2) VALUES ('name2', 2);"
Set objSehirEkle = objConn.execute(SQL)
```

Now if you want to do something with the returned recordset (objSehirEkle), you are referring only to the FIRST statement. You can access the result of the following statements by using the `NextRecordset` method, like so:

```
Set objNext = objSehirEkle.NextRecordset
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you insert multiple "sets" in a single INSERT statement (you're not saying which database and version you're using; I believe SQL Server 2008 and above and MySQL support this syntax):

```
INSERT 
  INTO Table ( Col1, Col2, Col3 ) 
  VALUES
    ( Value1, Value2, Value3 ), 
    ( Value4, Value5, Value6 ), 
    ( Value7, Value8, Value9 )
```

But as other people are saying, mind your SQL Injection exposure first.

Answer (score -1):

if you insert many fields using a jQuery plugin, you must control this in asp page.
I simulated a situation when you create many input fields by a select field. I set a hidden field to control the numbers of elements which I created on page. It's necessary pass this field for asp page form submit.
Try to do this (HTML Page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <title>Creating input fields</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $().ready(function(){
        $('#branches').change(function(){
          var nCounter = 0;
          var nr_branches = $('#branches').val();

          //-- Cleaning all elements
          var $divB = $('#divBranches');                    

          if (!$('#divBranches').is(':empty')){            
            while($divB.children('input').length >= 1) {
              $divB.children("input:first").remove();
            }                                    
          }          

          while(nCounter < nr_branches) {
            //-- Create an input field
            var input = $("<input type='text' class='bra' name='branche_nr_"+ nCounter +"' placeholder='Branche Nr."+ nCounter +"' />");
            $divB.append(input);            
            nCounter++;
          }

          //-- Set number of fields in hidden
          $('#qty_fields').val(nCounter);

        });        
      });
    </script>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <form name="frm" action="savefields.asp" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="college" placeholder="University Name" />
      <select name="branches" id="branches">
        <option value="0">-select your branche-</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="qty_fields" id="qty_fields" />
      <div id="divBranches"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />      
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

ASP Page (Submit):

```
<%
nQtdFields = request.form("qty_fields")
nCount = 0

do while cint(nCount) < cint(nQtdFields)  
  SQL = "insert into table_name(name) values ('"& request.form("branche_nr_" & nCount) &"')"
  Set objSehirEkle = objConn.execute(SQL)
  nCount = nCount + 1
loop
%>
```

That's it.
Rergards,
Vin.